# a script to print values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

i am trying to make a script that will take user input and print values, specifically, take a function as raw_input, and print the key in the dictionary when it is entered. I've tried to make it work a few ways, but I can't seem to get it down. I've asked a few questions on the forum the last few days and just to reiterate I'm now 4 days old in python years. can someone give me a pointer?

```
#dictionary of categories and their items
functions = {
'Absolute Value':{
'abs': 'syntax: abs(number), use:The abs function is used to determine the absolute  value 
}
'Round':{
'ro':'syntax: round(number), use: The round function is used to round a number down.'
}

#ask user for input as to which function they want
fnct=raw_input('Choose a function: abs, ro:')

#if a user chooses a function, map it to this key
if fnct=='abs':key='abs'
if fnct=='ro' :key='ro'

#if a user chooses a function, use the mapped key to print the key value
if fnct=='abs':print 'abs'
if fnct=='ro':print 'ro'
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What's your problem here? Also, in line 4 you're missing a closing `'`.

Comment: Could you please consider updating the title of your question to reflect the actual problem you're having. "a script to print values" is so vague that it could describe almost every program that outputs anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated your code, this should do exactly what you want (assuming you want to print the contents of a dictionary element based on user input) :

```
functions = {
    "abs":"syntax: abs(number), use:The abs function is used to determine the absolute value",
    "ro":"syntax: round(number), use: The round function is used to round a number down"
}

fnct = None

while fnct not in functions:
    fnct = raw_input("Choose a function: abs, ro :")

print(functions[fnct])
```

So the first lines define the `functions` dictionary, the `fnct = None` defines that variable so we don't run into an error on the first iteration of the while loop (since `input` isn't called yet), the loop checks if the entered value actually exists in the dictionary (and loops over asking another value if it doesn't exist, so that you don't run into a `KeyError` when trying to display something that doesn't exist in the dictionary), and finally it displays the content that corresponds to the `fnct` value.

Comment: I tried the code, it successfully prompts for a selection, but on selection there is some kind of error and the script exits without printing anything, I was thinking it's because of print(functions[fnct]) while fnct=None?

Comment: In python 2.x `input()` evaluates what the user types as python code, whereas `raw_input()` just treats it like a string. In python 3, there is no python-2-input equivalent, and `input()` just takes the role of `raw_input()`. Not that you really have to worry too much about any of that for now.

Comment: @andre  ha, i'm andres....but anyway, yeah it works, thanks a lot, i'm still in the beginning parts of the book but I need something useful to understand about python in order to keep the cogs working, thanks again. don't know why I didn't catch that too, already ran into that problem once